# Simple command for showing comments on shell script

Tags: linux, shell, comments, command

Suppose you have the following script:

```
# My comment line 1
# My comment line 2
# My comment line 3

echo "My script"
cd $MY_PATH
./anotherScript.ksh
```

Is there any command to show:

```
# My comment line 1
# My comment line 2
# My comment line 3
```

Alternatively, I could write a script to detect the first block of comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep '^\#.*$' myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `cat script.sh | grep ^\#` to only show those lines.

Comment: Why separately catting a piping where grep could it do itself?

Comment: I was under the impression that the pattern would have to be quoted if it was all in the grep command.  My mistake.  (And the reason that's an issue for me is that I've dealt with multiple levels of escaped quotes, and it's absolute hell)

Answer (score -1):

This will output your file to the grep command which will print each line with a "#"

`echo "My script" | grep "#"`

**EDIT I'M DUMB**

all you need to do is `grep '#' file` if I'm understanding correctly this time.

Comment: No, the `echo` command doesn't do what you think it does. You're looking for `cat`, but even then, see my comment on @rockerest's answer.

Comment: Yes yes I'm sure your correct. The man pages for grep would be great here. This is just what popped off my head. I didn't test at all.

Comment: @shakabara that's something you should never do when answering questions here. Please remove your answer, it's confusing future readers.